# In grails domainObject.save() in service class is not storing in database

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, grails-orm

I am using grails and I am trying to store 3 model object sequentially and these code has written in service class.
one of the model object is not storing in database.
I am using modelObject.save() in service class. Am I in wrong direction please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Insted of domainObject.save() use this domainObject.save(failOnError: true) save like this please post What exception your getting getting here...so that i can you ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a validation error in that instance. Instead of calling just `save()` and assuming that everything is valid, add a validity check so you can report the error(s) or retry, e.g.

```
modelObject.save()
if (modelObject.hasErrors()) {
    def errors = modelObject.errors
    // do something here with the `errors`
}
else {
    // do post-save work
}
```

There is another option that is recommended far too often and is almost always the wrong option, and that is to add `failOnError:true` to the `save()` call. It's bad logically when processing user-submitted data because you should expect mistakes, hacking attempts, etc., so in general a validation problem is not an *exceptional* occurrance and shouldn't trigger an exception.

A less theoretical reason why `failOnError:true` is that you trigger an exception, which will affect performance when there are a lot of them because of the significantly higher number of stack frames when using Groovy (we've all seen plenty mile-long Groovy stacktraces) and there's a runtime cost to filling in that data. But you would almost never need any of that stacktrace data, only the `errors` that occurred, and as you see above that's easily accessed without artificially slowing things down with exceptions.

Consider the analogous version using `failOnError`:

```
try {
    modelObject.save(failOnError:true)
    // do post-save work
}
catch (ValidationException e) {
    def errors = e.errors
    // do something here with the `errors`
}
```

It's basically the same code as before except the order is reversed, and this one wastes cpu cycles and memory and affects the scalability of your server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Burt, you are correct. it was happening from webservice-call, there was no member in springSecurity and I have defined in model as creator(nullable:false) so it was rolling back. Unfortunately I hadn't seen your response and simply wasted lot of time for finding this problem.

Comment: Cool, feel free to accept this as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use flush true :

```
   domainObject.save(flush: true)
```

The flush: true forces Hibernate to persist all changes to the database right away. It corresponds to what is known as flushing the session.

For more details follow this link  :http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/

Thanks Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Dipak for Reply. its true but in my scenario it wont useful because I am calling service by checking dirty property from domain so sometimes its giving me cyclic update and also some exception like Row was deleted by another transaction. but I resolved it.